What is the lifetimes on llvm::Type* instances?
I'm working with LLVM, and I'm wondering what the lifetimes are of the pointers. I can see that in the headers, they are heap allocated, but at what point are they added to the free list? Are they ever freed, do I get ownership and need to free them myself? Are they supposed to have a lifetime that is the same as the program? Are the automatically dealt with in the llvm::Module instance?
Thank you in advance for any help!

The types live as long as the LLVMContext, which is shared by a number of Modules and often lives until the end of main() in a compiler. Not necessarily. You don't need to free them, you do (really do!) need to make the LLVMContext go out of scope at the right moment.

In that case, there's a tick mark for you to tick. It helps findability.
